# "Relative" Cellular Chain Complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

There is an exercise in Hatcher (Section 2.2) which asks:

For a CW pair $(X,A)$ show there is a **relative cellular chain complex** formed by the groups $H_i(X_i,X_{i−1} ∪ A_i)$, having homology groups isomorphic to $H_n(X,A)$.

The following link is Hatcher's book:

http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf

To solve this problem, I think I should draw a huge diagram as in p.139, by augmenting some sequences, but I have no idea what sequence do I have to use.

Any hints??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First consider the homology of the pair $(X^i \cup A^{i+1}, X^{i-1} \cup A^i)$. This is a CW pair, so by excision $$H_i(X^i \cup A^{i+1}, X^{i-1} \cup A^i) \cong \tilde{H}_i(X^i \cup A^{i+1} / X^{i-1} \cup A^i) \cong \tilde{H}_i (X^i / X^{i-1} \cup A^i) \cong H_i(X^i, X^{i-1} \cup A^i)$$where the second isomorphism holds because adding the $(i+1)$-cells of $A$ will have no effect on $H_i$ since we're collapsing the $i$-skeleton of $A$ to a point in the quotient (this is basically a relative version of Lemma 2.34 in your book).

This means that we can substitute this into the long exact sequence of the pair $(X^i \cup A^{i+1}, X^{i-1} \cup A^i)$ to get

$$\cdots \to H_i(X^{i-1} \cup A^i) \to H_i(X^i \cup A^{i+1}) \to H_i(X^i, X^{i-1} \cup A^i) \to H_{i-1}(X^{i-1} \cup A^i) \to \cdots.$$

But $X^i \cup A^{i+1}$ fits into another long exact sequence, too: the long exact sequence of the pair $(X^{i+1} \cup A^{i+2}, X^i \cup A^{i+1})$, which is given by

$$\cdots \to H_{i+1}(X^{i+1} \cup A^{i+2}) \to H_{i+1}(X^{i+1}, X^i \cup A^{i+1}) \to H_i(X^i \cup A^{i+1}) \to \cdots$$

where we've identified the relative group in the middle by the same isomorphism above with $i$ replaced by $i+1$.

so define the map $H_{i+1}(X^{i+1}, X^i \cup A^{i+1}) \to H_i(X^i, X^{i-1}\cup A^i)$ to be the composition $H_{i+1}(X^{i+1}, X^i \cup A^{i+1}) \to H_i(X^i \cup A^{i+1}) \to H_i(X^i, X^{i-1} \cup A^i)$, where the first map is from the second long exact sequence above, and the second map is from the first long exact sequence above.

The remaining steps are to show that the sequence of these maps forms a chain complex and that the homology of this chain complex yields the homology of the pair $(X,A)$.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I have to show that the homology of the chain complex is isomorphic to the homology groups of $(X,A)$? I tried to follow the same argument as in Theorem 2.35 in the book, but I couldn't because in this case $H_i (X_i ∪A_{i+1} )→H_i (X_i ,X_{i−1} ∪A_i )$ is not injective.

Comment: I've made a slight edit to my answer--we are supposed to be fitting together the sequences for $(X^{i+1} \cup A^{i+2}, X^i \cup A^{i+1})$, $(X^i \cup A^{i+1}, X^{i-1} \cup A^i)$, and $(X^{i-1} \cup A^i, X^{i-2} \cup A^{i-1})$. Anyways, the diagram chase here is definitely more complicated. One thing that might help is that even though some maps might not be injective, their kernels are images of $H_k(A^k)$  (e.g., $H_i(X^{i-1} \cup A^i) \cong H_i(A^i)$) etc. under the various maps.

Comment: Also: the diagram you'll end up working with is pretty large. If you know the long exact sequences for triples, I am pretty sure you can get a smaller diagram where all the homology groups are relative and then apply a relative version of Lemma 2.34 to sort of duplicate Hatcher's argument, as long as you pick the right triples' sequences to fit together.

Comment: As a relative version of Lemma 2.34, I checked that the inclusion $(X_n,A_n) \to (X,A)$ induces an isomorphism $H_k(X_n,A_n) \to H_k(X,A)$ if $n>k$. But I still don't know what triple do I have to use. Thanks however, I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer:

You can use long exact sequences of the triples $A^n \subset X^{n-1} \cup A^n \subset X^n$:
$$
\cdots \to H_k(X^{n-1} \cup A^n, A^n) \xrightarrow{i_k} H_k(X^n, A^n) \xrightarrow{j_k} H_k(X^n, X^{n-1} \cup A^n) \xrightarrow{\partial_k} H_{k-1}(X^{n-1} \cup A^n, A^n) \to \cdots 
$$
Lemma 2.34 in Hatcher can be adapted in the following way:

**Lemma.** We have:

1. $H_k(X^n, X^{n-1} \cup A^n) = 0$ if $n \neq k$, and free abelian if $n=k$ with rank equal to the number of $n$-cells in $X$ not in $A$.
2. $H_k(X^{n}, A^{n}) \cong H_k(X^n \cup A^{n+1}, A^{n+1}) = 0$ for all $k > n$.
3. $H_n(X^{n+1}, A^{n+1}) \to H_n(X,A)$ induced by inclusion $(X^{n+1}, A^{n+1}) \hookrightarrow (X,A)$ is an isomorphism.

*Sketch of proof.*

1. $(X^n, X^{n-1} \cup A^n)$ is a good pair, and $X^n/(X^{n-1} \cup A^n)$ is a wedge sum of $n$-spheres, one for each $n$-cell not contained in $A$.
2. $(X^n, A^n)$ is a good pair, and $X^n/A^n$ is an $n$-complex, so $H_k(X^n, A^n) = 0$ for $k>n$ using Lemma 2.34(b) in Hatcher. The isomorphism $H_k(X^n, A^n) \cong H_k(X^n \cup A^{n+1}, A^{n+1})$ is excision.
3. $X^n \hookrightarrow X$ and $A^n \hookrightarrow A$ induce isomorphisms $H_k(X^n) \to H_k(X)$ and $H_k(A^n) \to H_k(A)$ for $k > n$ by Lemma 2.34(c) in Hatcher. Apply the 5-lemma to the long exact sequences for the triples $(X^n, A^n)$ and $(X,A)$. $\square$

By this lemma, and using the long exact sequence of triples, we get the commutative diagram:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
& & 0 & & & & & & \\
& & \big\uparrow & & & & & & \\
& & H_n(X^{n+1}, A^{n+1}) & & 0 & & & & \\
& & \big\uparrow & & \big\downarrow & & & & \\
& & H_n(X^n \cup A^{n+1}, A^{n+1}) & \xrightarrow{\quad \cong\quad} & H_n(X^n, A^n) & & & & \\
& & \big\uparrow & & \big\downarrow & & & & \\
\cdots & \longrightarrow & H_{n+1}(X^{n+1}, X^n \cup A^{n+1}) &\xrightarrow{\quad d_{n+1} \quad} & H_n(X^n, X^{n-1} \cup A^n) & \xrightarrow{\quad d_n \quad} & H_{n-1}(X^{n-1}, X^{n-2} \cup A^{n-2}) & \longrightarrow & \cdots \\
& & & & \big\downarrow & & \big\uparrow & & \\
& & & & H_{n-1}(X^{n-1} \cup A^n, A^n) & \xrightarrow{\quad \cong \quad} & H_{n-1}(X^{n-1}, A^{n-1}) & & \\
& & & & & & \big\uparrow & & \\
& & & & & & 0& & 
\end{array}
$$
The columns are exact. The isomorphisms $H_n(X^{n} \cup A^{n+1}, A^{n+1}) \cong H_n(X^n, A^n)$ and $H_{n-1}(X^{n-1} \cup A^n, A^n) \cong H_{n-1}(X^{n-1}, A^{n-1})$ come from excision, and the $d_n$ maps are the indicated compositions. Note $H_n(X, A) \cong H_n(X^{n+1}, A^{n+1}) \cong H_n(X^n \cup A^{n+1}, A^{n+1})/\mathrm{Im}(\partial_{n+1})$ by our lemma, where $\partial_{n+1}$ is the map $H_{n+1}(X^{n+1}, X^n \cup A^{n+1}) \to H_n(X^n \cup A^{n+1}, A^{n+1})$. The argument now is essentially the same as Theorem 2.35 in Hatcher.